# ggplot2 geom to graph the quantity of each point type (against a continuous axis)?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to figure out how to make a particular kind of graph. It looks like the kind of thing that would be super easy to do in R or ggplot2, but I must not be finding the right keywords to describe it. I've browsed the various geoms and read a few guides, but have come up empty-handed.

The essential issue is this: I have a list of emails, and the days on which they were sent (defined as days since 1/1/1970). I've successfully made a graph which shows **emails sent per `binwidth`**; e.g. if I sent one email per day and set the `binwidth` to 30 days, I'd get a bar with height 30.

What I'm *trying* to do is make a graph like this:

[image]

The graph above has **quantity of emails** on the x-axis, and the y-axis shows the **number of days on which the number of emails corresponded to that quantity**.

So for some example data, a list of days where emails were sent:

```
data <- c( 15562,15562,15562,15562,15563,15564,
           15564,15564,15566,15566, 15566,15566)
```

Rather than a graph with bars of heights 4, 1, 3, and 4 (corresponding to the number of emails on each day) I would want a graph with bars of heights 1, 1, and 2 (because there is 1 day where a single email was sent, 1 day where three emails were sent, and 2 days where four emails were sent).

Like in the example graph, I would want a continuous x-axis.

Does anyone know how to build a graph like the above?

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- c(15562,15562,15562,15562,15563,15564,15564,15564,15566,15566,15566,15566)
table(table(dat))
#1 3 4 
#1 1 2

#example with more data
set.seed(42)
dat <- sample(1:500,50000,TRUE)
hist(table(table(dat)),breaks=20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone wants to replicate [Stephen Wolfram personal analytics plots](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2012/03/the-personal-analytics-of-my-life/)? ;-)

No worries, to get results close to *Mathematica*-style visualisations, that Wolfram has been using, it's best to go with `lattice`, I think:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
histogram(~ FSC.H, gvhd10, xlab = "", ylab="", type = "density", 
          col="yellow", nint = 100, scales = list(y=list(draw=F)))
ltext(400,110,col="gray","distribution of emails per day")
```

[image]